# typescript - extend an ALIAS in a new file

Tags: typescript

I'm working with `typescript` and `angular 1.5`, and have an interesting situation.

In `angular.d.ts`, from **DefinitelyTyped**, `angular` actually declares an *alias* called **ng**, so it is used like this;

```
class SomeController {
   constructor($scope: ng.IScope) { }
}
```

Now, I want to extend `IScope` and add my own properties for the type safety. I'm a bit confused about how to go about this, though, as the following does not work...

```
declare module ng { 
   interface IRegisterScope extends ng.IScope {
      // ...
   }
}
```

I'm really confused about how to even begin going about this.
I'm importing angular using **es5** standard and my modules are compiled as **amd** according to my `tsconfig.json` file.

So this is what my file looks like, so far...

```
import "jquery";
import "angular";

class RegisterController {
   constructor($scope: ng.IScope) {
      // ...
   }
}

export = RegisterController;
```

and I want to extend **ng** to add a new interface, `IRegisterScope`.

Comment: I assume you only want to use that new interface in this file with `RegisterController`, only to get type safety/intellisense for `$scope`, correct?

Comment: At this time, I don't need it beyond this one controller, correct.

Comment: though knowing how to make it available elsewhere might not be bad knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply put the following above your `RegisterController` class:

```
interface IRegisterScope extends ng.IScope {
}
```

And then in the constructor of `RegisterController`:

```
constructor($scope: IRegisterScope) {
}
```

This way you don't export the new scope interface to pollute other files and still get the benefit of IntelliSense in this file.

If you want to it to make it available in other files, simply put it in a different file and reference it with in files you want to use it.

```
///<reference path="some_path_to_other_file/scopes.d.ts" />
```

**Update**

If you want `IRegisterScope` to be available under `ng`, you can do this.

scopes.d.ts:

```
declare module angular {
    interface IRegisterScope extends ng.IScope {
        someProperty: string;
    }
}
```

app.ts:

```
///<reference path="typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
///<reference path="scopes.d.ts" />

import "jquery";
import "angular";

class RegisterController {
   constructor($scope: ng.IRegisterScope) {
   }
}

export = RegisterController;
```

Comment: Right, but that doesn't add it to the `ng` module. It just stands on its own outside of the angular module. I was wanting to understand how to actually add it to the existing angular module.

Comment: Why would you want to change the module of an external library?

Comment: Aah, that's the problem I had. I have to declare the actual module in another file. I kept trying to do it inline with the actual implementation. Thank you!